# $f(r\mathbf{x}) = r^8f(\mathbf{x}) \Rightarrow \mathbf{x} \cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = 8f(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here's the full problem:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuously differentiable. If $f(r\mathbf{x}) = r^8f(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $r > 0$, show that $\mathbf{x} \cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = 8f(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I get the sense that the chain rule is relevant here, but I don't really know how to apply it to this problem. I seem to be missing something fundamental, and as a result I'm not quite sure where to start with this problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the left hand side: Write $f(rx)=f(rx_1,rx_2,...,rx_d)$. By the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dr}f(rx)=x_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(rx)+...+x_d\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_d}(rx)=x\cdot \nabla f(rx)$.